# Higher order function map implementation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, higher-order-functions

When I use transform operator(`map`) on a collection and just print the collection `element` it gives me `[()]` .Does anyone have any idea what is `[()]` is it array of void elements?

Code

`let p = [1,2,3,4,5].map{print($0)}`

`print(p)`

It also gives a warning `Constant 'p' inferred to have type '[()]', which may be unexpected`

Comment: You’re not returning anything in your map. What are you trying to map the array to?

Comment: @Andrew nothing I'm just print all the elements via map, check the code above.

Comment: Use `forEach()` instead of `map()` if you want just to print the elements. `map()` transforms, here you aren't transforming. Or did you meant `map{ "\($0)" }`?

Comment: Exactly right @Larme.

Comment: @Larme , @Andrew Yeah I know map() is a transform operator and for print we need to use `foreach`, however If you check my question I just want to figure out what is this `[()]` means?, ideally map should return empty array of int `[Int]`

Comment: () means void, which is the return type of the unnamed function { print($0) } and that function obviously returns no value, it just prints something and then returns nothing. [()] is array of void which is what you get when you map an array of things to void. Not a useful thing to do

Comment: () also represents the empty tuple and this type corresponds to void because they both only have 1 possible value. Unlike bool which has 2 possible values for example. There’s only one void and all voids are the same. This is why you see () meaning void, they’re essentially the same type

Comment: @Shadowrun that make sense!!! thanks for commenting.